# How to generate more pbf zoom levels with mbtiles file?

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles, pbf, maptiler, mbutil

I have a 8GB canada.mbtiles vector file which contains all of Canada up to zoom level 14.

How do I generate zoom 15,16 from this canada.mbtiles file?  The goal is to serve smaller pbf on z15,16 for a mobile web application(mapbox-gl-js).

Tried mbutil from https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil, extracted all pbf files into folder 0~14, what to do next?  I assume it should be possible to generate z15,16 from z14 given nothing is changed, only getting smaller tile.

File: [metadata.json](https://pastebin.com/gr6GZqyd)

The mbtiles file is extracted into 0~14 folders +  metadata.json

[image]

Comment: Adding those additional levels of zoom won't, as you note, add any information. There's no point making these tiles, just get your client to "overzoom" the highest available level.